# Do QGIS layer definition files (qlr) support joined layers?

Tags: qgis

I tried to save a qlr file for a shp layer joined to an xls file, but when I load it, the join definition isn't there anymore...

Join definition is present in the qlr file, so I assume it should work.

Has anybody already tried this ?

Comment: Did you check the layer id in the qlr file matches the layer id in your project?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Matthias. I am trying to load the qlr in an empty project... I also tried with a csv instead of the xls, but had the same problem. Checking the content of both qlr files, it appears that there is no reference to the xls/csv file, only to its id in the join definition, which explains why the join isn't restored : the joined xls/csv isn't loaded.

Comment: I think you need to load manually the xls/csv file in the empty project. Or work on the same project that remembers shape and xls/csv and qlr file. Why trying to load your layer inside a new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same question, and eventually figured out that grouping your xls/csv with your shapefile enables you to save the group as qlr.

Then, simply load the qlr : shp and xls/csv are equally loaded whithin the group you created.

Hope that might help other people having same question.

Comment: Great trick, works perfectly !

Answer (score 2):

Once your XLS file is joined to your shapefile, then **save your shapefile with a new name** in order to save the added columns in the attribute table of your shapefile (`right-click on layer > Save As...`). If you don't do that, the joined columns seem to be included in the attributes table but this is virtual and not properly saved within your shapefile attributes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, wiltomap. I know that I can save my layer to keep joined fields, but I would like to have a dynamic join.